# Apple Notification Services: Windows server requires re-importing the APNs certificate

Tags: ssl, apple-push-notifications, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I've been successfully running Apple Push Notifications on my Windows Development server (win 7) until a weekend power failure at the office caused my box to shut down (it lasted longer than the UPS unit). I then discovered that the push notifications stopped working until I re-imported the .p12 certificate into the server.

Then just to test, I shut down and restarted the development box, and again found that the push notifications were not working, and once more I needed to re-import the .p12 certificate.

Surely this is not correct. The certificates should not need to be imported after every power failure?

For importing the certificates, I used the steps as shown here:  https://arashnorouzi.wordpress.com/2011/04/13/sending-apple-push-notifications-in-asp-net-%e2%80%93-part-3-apns-certificates-registration-on-windows/

Is there a way to do this so the .p12 will not need to be re-imported every time the machine restarts?

Thanks!