# Why won't server certificate persist after a reboot?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, certificate, apple-push-notifications, x509certificate, x509certificate2

I've written a Windows TCP (NOT IIS) server program in VB that provides the backend for an enterprise iPhone app that I have also developed. The system utilizes Apple Push Notifications, and that works fine, unless the server reboots for whatever reason.

Part of the Push Notification system is the inclusion of Apple certificates on the server. [I followed the steps shown here](https://arashnorouzi.wordpress.com/2011/04/13/sending-apple-push-notifications-in-asp-net-%E2%80%93-part-3-apns-certificates-registration-on-windows/) to install the necessary certificates, and even though it's for ASP.NET applications, it works for my Windows-based server. Except, as I said, a reboot requires installing the certificates all over again.

[I found this page on Server Fault that suggests adding a user to the certificate](https://serverfault.com/questions/665140/certificate-stops-working-after-computer-reboot) through the MMC snap-in, but that didn't work either.

Two questions: Following the steps shown on the Server Fault page, do I need to add a specific user? The only users that pop up are SYSTEM (which I tried), Administrators(ComputerName/Administrators) (also tried) and "S-1-1-5-blah, blah" (didn't try). Would there need to be a different user added to make it work?

Q2: If this won't ever work, is there a different way?

Full disclosure: [This is the second time I have submitted this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44633554/apple-notification-services-windows-server-requires-re-importing-the-apns-certi), but the previous one (four months ago) was never responded to. I'm hoping someone who knows will see this.

Thanks for any advice.

**AFTERTHOUGHT:** The instructions I linked to above say to install the certificates to Personal/Certificates. Maybe this is wrong? This stuff is way over my head, so I don't understand the function of all the different stores.

Comment: What is your symptom (what exception, from where)?  How are you importing the certificate?  If you unplug the computer (completely avoiding any safe process shutdown) does it repro?  99.5% sure your answer is `PersistKeySet`.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.

The page on Server Fault left out something. I needed to add a user that the system would recognize to the Permissions list. I added my user authentication, selected it, and after that the certificate persisted after a restart.

It is at least working on my development server. I haven't tried it yet on my production server.

**Update:** Works the same on the production server. Also, instead of using my user authentication, I used the IUSR authentication, meaning that it should work even after my name is removed from the active directory.